# Modal disappearing instantly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner, trying to implement 'click' event listener to pop up a modal. But as soon as I click the link the modal appears and disappear instantly.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById(btn");
const modal= document.getElementById("modal");

const showModal = function (el, modalId) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modalId.classList.remove("hidden");
  });
};

showModal(btn, modal);
```

```css
.hidden{
 display: none
}
```

```html
<a class='btn'> Click </a>
<div id='modal' class='hidden'> Modal Content </div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet. As you can see there's a `"` missing in the getElementById

Comment: There's also no element with id `btn`

Comment: Ya there are a lot of typos pardon them, I still learning to use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you should define `id="btn"` on your a tag to be able to do
`document.getElementById("btn")`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");

    const showModal = function(el, modalId) {
      el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        modalId.classList.remove("hidden");
      });
    };

    showModal(btn, modal);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a id="btn"> Click </a>
<div id='modal' class='hidden'> Modal Content </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try this.

Comment: If it solved your issue could you mark the reply to close the topic ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks You so much guys for responding. I found my mistake, I was using 'link' tag with empty 'href' attribute, due to which the page was reloading ever time I clicked it. I simply replaced the links with button tag and now it is working just fine.

Although I still want to know if it is possible to stop the page from reloading when link element is clicked.

Also, thank you for highlighting the 'class/id' typo.

Comment: This can be added to the question as an edit, instead of an answer